# Building a grid and snap to it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I'm trying to make a grid where I can snap images to each of my "boxes" inside the grid.

I have created a "look a like" grid just using an image with the dimensions of 80px*80px and set it to repeat. And then I have a functions that shows what I want to achive, but not in the right way:

```
$(function() {
   $("#draggable5").draggable({
      grid: [80, 80]
   });
});
```

You can check the it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/SvZMr/1/

What I want to do, is to use the snap function:

```
$( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ snap: ".CityContainer" });
```

In the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SvZMr/1/) I have a yellow square than only snaps to the .CityContainer. I want this square to be able to snap to each of the squares in my grid (like to blue square that moving in an 80*80 grid).

**My question is**: in order to achive what I want. Do I have to manually create each div of the squares in the grid, like:

```
<div class="square s1"></div>
<div class="square s2"></div>
```

and so on?
Or is there an easier way (without plugins)?

It would take a lot of time if I needed a 10*10px grid in a 960px wide container fx.

I hope that you can help me out. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create html content on the fly with jquery with append for example.

You can also access the generated html via jquery (normal selectors), just the execution order matters, of cause...

Small example:

```
for(var i = 0;i<50;i++){
    $(".CityContainer").append(
            "<div id='\"'draggable\"" + i
            + " class=\"dropbox ui-widget-content\"></div>"
        );
}
$(".dropbox").droppable();

$( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ snap: ".dropbox", grid: [80,80] });
```

I've modified your fiddle, find it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/SvZMr/3/

Comment: Thanks you! I deleted the grid: [80,80] and now it pretty much works like I intended it to. Snapping to the top left corner of each of the squares.